# Colour on gggplot with significance bars

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am having trouble with creating coloured violin plots on ggplot. I have been finding a workaround to create graphs with significance lines between the violin plots, this involves creating seperate dataframes then adding these as geom_lines to the origional plot.

I initially wanted the plots to be grey, however this has now changed and I would like couloured violin plots. However this does not seem to work.

Below is my code for the grey violin plots (that works):

```
df1 <- data.frame(a = c(1, 1:2,2), b = c(1.5, 1, 1, 1.5))
df2 <- data.frame(a = c(1, 1:3,3), b = c(0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0.5))
df3 <- data.frame(a = c(1, 1:4,4), b = c(-0.5, -1, -1, -1, -1, -0.5))
df4 <- data.frame(a = c(2, 2:3,3), b = c(15, 15.5, 15.5, 15))
df5 <- data.frame(a = c(2, 2:4,4), b = c(16, 16.5, 16.5, 16.5, 16))
df6 <- data.frame(a = c(3, 3:4,4), b = c(17, 17.5, 17.5, 17))

  pp <- EditedDF1 %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=ct_marshallFAC, y=logGFAP)) + 
  geom_violin(fill="#CCCCCC") +
  stat_summary(fun.y=median, geom="point", size=2, color="red") +
  geom_boxplot(width=0.1, outlier.shape = NA) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(), axis.text.x = element_blank(), 
  axis.ticks.x = element_blank()) +`
  labs(x="", y= "Log GFAP(ng/ml)") +
  ylim(-2, 18)  +
  theme(legend.position="bottom")

  pp

  aa <- pp +
  geom_line(data = df1, aes(x = a, y = b)) + annotate("text", x = 1.5, y 
  = 0.2, label = "***", size = 6 ) +
  geom_line(data = df2, aes(x = a, y = b)) + annotate("text", x = 1.5, y 
  = -0.8, label = "***", size = 6) +
  geom_line(data = df3, aes(x = a, y = b)) + annotate("text", x = 1.5, y 
  = -1.8, label = "***", size = 6) +
  geom_line(data = df4, aes(x = a, y = b)) + annotate("text", x = 2.5, y 
  = 15.8, label = "***", size = 6) +
  geom_line(data = df5, aes(x = a, y = b)) + annotate("text", x = 2.5, y 
  = 16.8, label = "***", size = 6) +
  geom_line(data = df6, aes(x = a, y = b)) + annotate("text", x = 3.5, y 
  = 17.8, label = "*", size = 6)
```

As soon as I add a code for colour such as:

```
pp <- EditedDF1 %>% 
ggplot(aes(x=ct_marshallFAC, y=logGFAP, fill=EditedDF1$ct_marshallFAC)) 
+ 
geom_violin() + (The rest of the above)
```

it colours the violin plots, but removes the significance lines from the plot, not running the geom line section and stating : Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (4): fill

or

```
    pp <- EditedDF1 %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=ct_marshallFAC, y=logGFAP)) + 
  geom_violin(fill=ct_marshallFAC) + (The rest of the above)
```

it says: Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (2048): fill

I would really appreciate any help on the matter, as I feel it should be simple to add the colour but it is not proving so!

Many thanks,

Dan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each `geom_line` call is inheriting all the previous `aes()` assignations, including fill. Use `inherit.aes = FALSE` in each call for a quick fix:

```r
...
geom_line(..., inherit.aes = FALSE) +
...
```

This should *hopefully* work, but if not there may be other things needing changed. Do post a code sample/reproducible example which can hopefully help get to a working code for you.